# Prove $\lim_{x\rightarrow0} g \circ f(x)\neq g(\lim_{x\rightarrow0} f(x))$

Tags: limits

Let $f(x) = \lbrace 0$ if x $\in\Bbb{Q}$
, 1 if x $\notin\Bbb{Q}\rbrace$

and $g(x) = \lbrace 1$ if x $\in\Bbb{Q}$
, $0 $ if x $\notin\Bbb{Q}\rbrace$

Prove that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0} g \circ f(x)\neq g(\lim_{x\rightarrow0} f(x))$$

My intuition tells me that the LHS has limit and that RHS doesn't, but I have no basis for this idea and I always thought continuity commutes so the limit should be the same. Where am I wrong, and how should I view this question?

Comment: $g$ is not continuous, so you cannot commute. Your intuititon is good. In fact $g\circ f\equiv 1$.

Comment: $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$ doesn't exist, so $g(\lim_{x\to0}f(x))$ doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Why wouldn't the limit exist exactly? Aren't all the number as you get to zero rational and you get the limit as 0? I just don't understand how to know it doesn't have a limit

Comment: No, there are both rational and non-rational numbers arbitrary close to $0$: both the rationals and the non-rationals are dense in ${\mathbb R}$.